# multiple record select Dynamics crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Using crm when I have multiple select how can I change(edit) multiple selected records? Also is there any possibility to put permissions for different users accessing multiple edit? For example a super admin and a user will see specific fields when the edit multiple records page appear.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk edit feature is OOB. To edit records in a bulk way select records you want to edit and click edit button on the toolbar. This video demonstrates that - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zv7C06IRV4U

To limit possibility of bulk editing open security role you want to change that privilege, open "Business Management" tab and use "Bulk Edit" privilege in "Miscellaneous Privileges" section to allow/disallow bulk editing functionality for a security role.

Comment: Thank you @andrii-butenko !! How can I allow disallow a specific section in bulk edit for a security role?

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not possible.